# $(2+z^2) f(z) + 3 z + 4 = f(z+1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations

Consider the equation

$(2+z^2) f(z) + 3 z + 4 = f(z+1)$

Such that $f(z)$ is analytic near the positive real axis and the functional equation holds for real $z>0$.

Can we express Some solutions for $f(z)$ ?

Notice $g(z+1) = (z^2) g(z)$ is expressed by the square of the gamma function.

Comment: Notice f has at most 3 fixpoints where the equation still holds , it follows from substitute f(z) = z ---> degree 3 polynomial.